# xml.dom.minidom python issue

Tags: python, xml

```
from xml.dom.minidom import *

resp = "<title> This is a test! </title>"

rssDoc = parseString(resp)

titles = rssDoc.getElementsByTagName('title')

moo = ""

for t in titles:
    moo += t.nodeValue;
```

Gives the following error:

```
main.py, line 42, in
       get moo += t.nodeValue;
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<title>` node contains a text node as a subnode.  Maybe you want to iterate through the subnodes instead?  Something like this:

```
from xml.dom.minidom import *

resp = "<title> This is a test! </title>"

rssDoc = parseString(resp)

titles = rssDoc.getElementsByTagName('title')

moo = ""

for t in titles:
    for child in t.childNodes:
        if child.nodeType == child.TEXT_NODE:
            moo += child.data
        else:
            moo += "not text "

print moo
```

For learning xml.dom.minidom you might also check out the [section in Dive Into Python](http://www.diveintopython.org/xml_processing/parsing_xml.html).

Answer (score 1):

Because  is not a text node, but an element node. The text node which contains the " This is a test! " string is actually a child node of this element node.

So you can try this (untested, not assumes existence of the text node):

```
if t.nodeType == t.ELEMENT_NODE:
    moo += t.childNodes[0].data
```

Comment: Thanks. Would be handy if elements had a .content member imho

Answer (score 0):

because `t.nodeType` is not equal to `t.TEXT_NODE` of course.